# What does `return -1 || exit -1` mean?

Tags: bash

I'm confused by the following bash line, written by someone else:

```
return -1 || exit -1
```

What does it mean? I understand the `||` construct means if the first part (in this case, `return -1`) failed (i.e. return a non-zero code), then the second part (`exit -1`) is executed. What's also strange is this statement is not part of any function, but in the main body of the script.

I appreciate someone who explains this to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here, `return` is a trick to exit when the script is `source` -ed  and `exit` is usual that it will exit a shell.

So essentially the above condition is to exit from the execution loop of the script whether it is `source` -ed or executed.

Also note that, the negative return values are not supported in `bash`. In both cases, you would get exit status of 255, not -1.

Comment: Mayb also note that negative status codes are not generally correct or supported.

Comment: An exit status of `-1` is simply undefined; an implementation doesn't have to treat it as an 8-bit value or clear any higher bits.

Comment: This is POSIX-compliant behaviour (see [`return`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#return) — including the behaviour when the script is being `.` dotted (aka `source`d in Bash).  See also [`exit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exit).